# Can't connect to GoDaddy mysqli database via PHP script

Tags: php, mysqli, shared-hosting

Been trying for ages but just can't get my php script to connect to a mysqli database on my GoDaddy server. I've checked the username, password, database name countless times. Here's the script. Grateful for any advice.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","Villa1234");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Prospects WHERE email = '$loginEmail'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows == 1) {
        $firstRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $status = $firstRow['status'];
        $access = $firstRow['access'];
        $pid = $firstRow['prospect_ID'];
        if ($status == "Pending") {
            $loginResult = "pending";
        } else if ($access == "locked") {
            $loginResult = "locked";    
        } else {
            $storedPassword = $firstRow['password'];
            if ($storedPassword === $password) {
                $loginResult = "success";
                $firstName = $firstRow['firstname'];
                $_SESSION['loginEmail'] = $loginEmail;
            } else {
                $loginResult = "incorrect password";
            };
        };
    } else if ($rows == 0) {
        $loginResult = "email not registered";
    };  
};
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Without errors and outputs, its impossible to debug.

Comment: Add if ($con->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
} to your code and report back to us on the actual error message.

Comment: And, just to nitpick: it's a MySQL database, not mysqli. Mysqli is the database connection handler you're using in PHP.

Comment: I get this error message string(100) "mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'julesgru2'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" Please note that I've replaced my real username with "username" in my original question but, of course, the error message here shows my actual username.

Comment: Have you gone back and checked the details in the Database name and user creation and assignment of the user to the database etc where you set this up?

Comment: Just got through to GoDaddy and they got me to create a new database user and working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this: (Even if it doesn't work, it will atleast display the error you are facing)

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$con = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","Villa1234");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Prospects WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bid_param("s", $loginEmail);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->bind_result();
if($result->num_rows==1){
    while($firstRow=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $status = $firstRow['status'];
        $access = $firstRow['access'];
        $pid = $firstRow['prospect_ID'];
        if ($status == "Pending") {
        $loginResult = "pending";
        }
        else if ($access == "locked") {
        $loginResult = "locked";    
        }
        else {
        $storedPassword = $firstRow['password'];
        if ($storedPassword === $password) {
            $loginResult = "success";
            $firstName = $firstRow['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['loginEmail'] = $loginEmail;
        } else {
            $loginResult = "incorrect password";
        }
        }
    }
}
else if ($rows == 0) {
    $loginResult = "email not registered";
}
?>
```